# What did my teacher mean by 'db.sqlite3' will fall short in bigger real word problems?

Tags: python, django

I am very new to programming and this site too... An online course that I follow told me that it is not possible to manage bigger databases with db.sqlite3, what does it mean anyway?

Comment: As long as (almost) the entire file fits into memory, sqlite can outperform databases. But from the moment the size of the file is gigantic, it will not be cached, and will require a lot of reading and swapping to get the relevant parts in the cache. A database like MySQL for example will cache index structures and avoid roundtrips to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Choice of Relational Database Management Systems (RDBMS) is dependent on your use case. The different options available have different pros and cons and hence, for different applications, some are more suitable than others.

I typically use SQLite (only for development purposes) and then switch to MySQL for my Django projects.

**SQLite:** Is file based. You can actually see the file in your project directory so all the CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete) is done directly onto that file. Also, all the underlying code for the RDBMS is quite small in size. So all this makes it good for applications which don't require intensive use of databases or perhaps require offline storage e.g. IoT, small websites etc. When you try to use it for big projects that require intensive use of databases e.g. online stores, you run into many problems because the RDBMS is not as well developed as MySQL or PostgreSQL. The primary problem is a lack of concurrency i.e. only one device can be writing to the database at a time because operations are serialised.

**MySQL:** Is one of the most popularly used and my personal favourite (very easy to configure and use with Django). It's based on the client/server database model and not a file like SQLite and is very scalable i.e. it is capable of way more than SQLite and you can use it for many different applications that require heavy use of the RDBMS. It has better security, allows for concurrent operations and outperforms PostgreSQL in performance when you need to do lots of reading operations.

**PostgreSQL:** Is also a very strong option and capable of most of the stuff that MySQL can do but handles clients in a different way and it has an edge over MySQL in SELECTs and INSERTs. MySQL is still soooo much more widely used than PostgreSQL though.

There are also many other options on the market. You can take a look at this [article](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/popular-databases) which compares a bunch of them. But to answer your question, SQLite is very simplistic compared to the other options and stores everything in a file in your project rather than on a server, so as a result, there is little security, lack of concurrency etc. This is fine when developing and for use cases that do not require major use of databases but will not cut it for big projects.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a matter of how big the DB is. SQLite DB can be very big, hundreds of Gigabytes.

It is a matter of how many user are using the application (you mention django) concurrently. As SQLite only support one writer at a time, the other are queued. Fortunately, you can have many concurrent readers.

So if you have a lot of concurrent access (that are not explicitly marked are read-only) then SQLite is not a good choice anymore. You'll prefer something like PostgreSQL.

BTW, everything is better explained in the [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) ;)

Comment: For someone who is still a beginner, do I need to switch it?

Comment: IMHO : use SQLite as long as you don't have to switch to something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a database for your project is like selecting any other technology. It depends on your use case.

Size isn't the issue, complexity is. SQLite3 databases can grow as big as 281 terabytes. Limits on number of tables, columns & rows are also pretty decent.

If your application logic requires SQL operations like:

1. `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`, `FULL OUTER JOIN`
2. `ALTER TABLE`, `ADD CONSTRAINT`, etc..
3. `DELETE`, `INSERT`, or `UPDATE` on a `VIEW`
4. Custom user permissions to read/write

Then SQLite3 should **not** be your choice of database as these SQL features are not implemented in SQLite3.

Comment: I would rather say : Then SQLite3 should not be your choice of database **if you need** these SQL features.